# nodejs function syntax in module.export

Tags: node.js

consider the following:

```
let y = doSomething(){ //doesn't work
    console.log('sdf')
}

let y = function doSomething(){ //works
    console.log('sdf')
}



module.exports = {
    getAll(){

    }
}
```

I had never seen this sort of function(inside the module.exports) is it a call or definition?
It differs in that it doesn't have a keyword function, yet it's exported. What is it called? Does it have a specific name, *most importantly*, what are we actually doing in here? Please leave me a link to finding out more on this sort of definition if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let y = function doSomething() {}` called [Function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_expressions)

> a name can be provided with a function expression. Providing a name allows the function to refer to itself, and also makes it easier to identify the function in a debugger's stack traces:

```js
module.exports = {
  getAll(){}
}
```

It exports an anonymous object which has a `getAll()` method. It's called [Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)